# golang , How to count elements in struct type interface{}?

Tags: go, struct, slice

I'm rather new in Go, but trying hard..

I'm trying to write some logick, that need to check if an attribute of struct consists only of one element, or the first element has only one child.

Main struct is this :

```
type ChartOptins struct {
    Filters Filter `json:"filters"`
    Charts interface{} `json:"charts"`
}
```

Charts are born to be a composition of arrays of structure like this :

```
    $filters = array(
        "filters" => array(
            "DayStart" => "12-01-2015",
            "DayEnd" => "12-05-2015",
            "TimePeriods"=> array(
                array("qqq","www"),
            ),
            "lines" => array(
                "first","avokado","drunduki"
            )

        ),
        "charts" => array(
            "noagg" => array(
                array(
                    "name" => "HOLD",
                    "type" => "line"
                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "UKKR",
                    "type" => "line"
                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "SVO",
                    "type" => "line"
                ),
            ),
            "oracle" => array(
                array(
                    "name" => "TDD",
                    "type" => "line"
                ),
            ) 
        ),
    );
```

Into the stuct `ChartOptions` I parse the JSON from POST request. JSON looks like this :

```
{ "filters": { "dayStart": "11-10-2015", "dayEnd": "21-10-2015", "timePeriods": [ [ "qqq", "www" ] ], "lines": [ "first", "avokado", "drunduki" ] }, "charts": { "noagg": [ { "name": "HOLD", "type": "line" } ] } }
```

So , `charts` can have only 1 source and 1 element in it, or any amount of elements in any amount of  sources.

```
"charts" : { "noagg": [ { "name": "HOLD", "type": "line" } ] }
or
"charts" : { "noagg": [ { "name": "HOLD", "type": "line" } , { "name": "TDD", "type": "line" } , { "name": "SVO", "type": "line" } ] }
```

Of cource, this is the JSON elements that comes to go script, and i parse them into interface{}. When I tried to use `len()`, Go said that I cant use it on interface..

What is the best practice to work with the amount of elements, and what is the best way to achieve such a check?

Comment: try using `reflect` package

Comment: can you give some examples?

Comment: Don't parse into an `ìnterface{}` (which you should not use if new to Go anyway) but into some appropriate struct with a noagg slice and do `len` on that slice.

Comment: I'll try to use slices for this too, but for this it is nesessary to declare struct type for each slice to the bottom of the tree...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i understand you just need define structures for mapping json properly. It can be like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type ChartOptins struct {
    Filters map[string]interface{} `json:"filters"`
    Charts  map[string][]Chart     `json:"charts"`
}

type Chart struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}

func main() {
    const jsonStream = `{
        "filters": { "dayStart": "oneortwo", "dayEnd": "oneorthree", "timePeriods": [ [ "qqq", "www" ] ], "lines": [ "first", "avokado", "drunduki" ] }, 
        "charts": { "noagg": [ { "name": "HOLD", "type": "line" }, { "name": "UKKR", "type": "line" }, { "name": "SVO", "type": "line" } ], "oracle": [ { "name": "TDD", "type": "line" } ] } 
    }`

    var co ChartOptins
    json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream)).Decode(&co)

    fmt.Println(co)

    for k, v := range co.Charts {
        fmt.Printf("key: %v\n", k)
        for _, ch := range v {
            fmt.Printf("Name: %v, type: %v\n", ch.Name, ch.Type)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the name of source to be dynamic, that is why I used interface. I found that ```map[string]Charts``` can be used, but now i Get erros that array cannot be parsed into my new structs..

The name of "source" can be x, y, ..., n, and there might be several sources in one moment..

Comment: Can you send dynamic object name in additional json field? Do you know the structure of this object?

Comment: I know the structure. But I can't send additional "name" attribute. I'll write the structure of the main array in question. Updated the question body

Comment: So you don't know name of object with array of Chats, right? ('noagg" for example)

Comment: It can be one of the list, but the list is dynamic. I mean that now there are only 3 source elements. But later there might be 10, or more sources of data, for charts

Comment: I wrote the whole test array , that comes to the go app from POST  with the format of JSON..in the body of my question

Comment: I got error : ```JSON decode error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string```

Here is my json: ```{ "filters": { "dayStart": "oneortwo", "dayEnd": "oneorthree", "timePeriods": [ [ "qqq", "www" ] ], "lines": [ "first", "avokado", "drunduki" ] }, "charts": { "noagg": [ { "name": "HOLD", "type": "line" }, { "name": "UKKR", "type": "line" }, { "name": "SVO", "type": "line" } ], "oracle": [ { "name": "TDD", "type": "line" } ] } }``` May be that would be easier?

Comment: with your json https://play.golang.org/p/isgxl0qlRv . I just didnt implement Filter structure

Comment: works like a charm. I rewrote your struct with mistake firstly. Now all works! Thank You!  Edit your main answer, and I'll  point it as the solution =)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an exemple keeping interface:
https://play.golang.org/p/Eu6Hj6ddSE

Just change:
 `Charts interface{}` witch `Charts []interface{}`
if v is you ChartOptins then to get your len use .() operator on interface

```
fmt.Println(len(v.Charts.([]interface{})))
```